# Discord.js: MessageCollector not collecting

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make a Discord bot that collects messages in a DM channel. The `messageCollector` does not collect anything. Take a look at this fragment:

```
var dmChannel = message.author.dmChannel;
if (message.author.dmChannel === null) {
  console.log(`Created dm channel`);
  dmChannel = await message.author.createDM();
}
var filter = m => m.content === 'm' && m.content === 'l' && m.content === 'r' && m.content === 'd' && m.content === 'e' && m.content === 'i';
const actions = dmChannel.createMessageCollector(filter, { time: 600000 });
```

When I send any of the letters, it does not collect them. I have a theory that if you create the collector with a command in another server, that that bugs out and doesn't do anything? I'm really not sure. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hah, I figured out that the fault lies in `filter`. It's supposed to be this:

```
var filter = m => m.content === `m` || m.content === `l`... ;
```

`&&` must be replaced with `||` because `||` means or, not and.